# I'm running a full node. How can I help speed up other people's transactions?

Tags: iri-node, spam

Is there a software that I can use to automatically create 0-value transactions (spam) using my own node? I have found one that uses the browser, but that one is very slow and is currently not working either (not updated?).
Edit: The question is not IF/WHY spamming the network is good. I assume spamming from my own node is good for the network. The Q is HOW to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use POW on your own node to speed ut other ppl's transactions, you actually only need to install NodeJS and use the js-lib. It has the same feature as the wallet currenlty have - promotion of transactions. This takes the other person's transaction-hash as parameter and will promote it as defined in the other parameters you specify...

https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.lib.js#promotetransaction

If you need help to create a script to be run - just ask.

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I have just used the copy&paste instructions at iota.partners. I have little knowledge of using Linux (Ubuntu 17.4), so I would love some instructions.

Comment: PS: Maybe the script could also be run on another computer, that means doing the POW on another computer in order to not exhauste the nodes recources (I've made it available for others to be used also).

Answer (score 0):

you can use this [spammer](https://github.com/pRizz/iota-transaction-spammer-webapp) client-side

just comment out the line 227 in [transactionSpammer.js](https://github.com/pRizz/iota.transactionSpammer.js/blob/977a7403c622c8addc6a630b21940970da2c15a0/src/transactionSpammer.js). this way the PoW is done by the full node. make sure you exclude the attachToTangle command in the --remote-limit-api configuration option of the IRI.

in theory you could also let the spammer run as a nodejs module on your server. you have to tweak the repo a bit to make this work.

Comment: Thanks, but I have tried this spammer. I would prefer to use it on my home computer (not the node). But I get this error code: "Error occurred while checking if node is synced". Maybe because my node use http instead of https?

Comment: well like it says: your node is not synched. does LatestMilestoneIndex=LatestSolidMilestoneIndex and does it equal the latest #botbox value???

Comment: Hmm. When I check the Grafana interface, it is in sync (also compared to the botbox-thread at Slack). But in my light wallet, it sometimes is lagging behind 1-2 milestones. I am able to send transactions, though.

Comment: maybe you have to update to the latest iota.lib.js v0.4.6. i think that spammer app still uses a old one.

Comment: Doesn't seem like anyone is maintaining that app any more? I added a comment on issue #22. Sorry, I'm not able to do that change myself...